# ECS/POS printing text with different justification on same line

Tags: c#, printing

on our receipt we would like for the ECS printing to print left and right

the result should look something like this

```
test print                   100
test print                   200
```

can this be done?

this is what i used as reference
http://content.epson.de/fileadmin/content/files/RSD/downloads/escpos.pdf

and i've tried the settings

"Print and feed n lines" and "Print and reverse feed n lines"

print and feed 0 lines does not work and i cant get reverse feed to work either.

Comment: These kind of printers use fixed-pitch fonts.  Which makes it very simple to align text, just insert enough spaces.  String.Format() with width specifiers gets the job done.

Comment: Thank you, i think we can make it work now with what you said.